# Groovy version 2.4.2 for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, eclipse-plugin, gvm

How can I make a groovy project in eclipse use a custom Groovy Library?

I'm new to Groovy and I'm confused as to how to use it in Eclipse.

I installed the Groovy Plugin to Eclipse, every time I make a project, the Groovy library used is version 2.3.7.

I downloaded the Groovy SDK version 2.4.2 and want to use it with my eclipse, however I can't seem to do it as when I try to add a new Groovy library, nothing happens.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Groovy-plugin for Eclipse comes with it's own Groovy-compilers. It is not possible to add your own groovy compilers.

Version 2.9.1 of the groovy-eclipse plugin does not have the 2.4.x compiler included. In Version 2.9.2 the compiler 2.4.x is included. In Order to install it, use the update-site http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.4/ . I tried it, and in it works (there has been a bugfix: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues/112)

Comment: Thanks @Edward, this answers my question. I'd like to ask though, I used this link [http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4/](http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4/) instead of the one you provided. Is it correct for me to assume that the link I used contains everything since it's tagged as release? While the one you provided contains increments?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) and installed the plugin from http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.8

The version of groovy I installed is 2.5.4